# How To Count Users Appropriately

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display the number of `AppUsers` for each app, by `AppName`and `CategoryName` with the total number of users sorted in descending order, so the most popular are at the top.

My attempted code below failed to count the number of users for each app, I also wasn't sure on how to join them with the other tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT
COUNT (au."AppUserId") "No. Of Users",
CAST(a."AppName" AS varchar2(30)) AS "AppName", --Cast to reduce column size in SQL Plus
ac."CategoryName"
FROM BR_APP a, BR_APPCATEGORY ac, BR_APPUSER au;
```

I'm finding it difficult to figure out how to count the users and display how many of them use each app.
[image: U]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

If you are not learning this in your class/books, then you should bring it up.  You don't want to be learning something in computers that was superseded over 20 years ago.

Then, if you want to count something, `GROUP BY` is expected in the query:

```
SELECT a.appname, ac.categoryname, COUNT(*) as num_users
FROM BR_APP a JOIN
     BR_APPCATEGORY ac
     ON a.appcategoryid = ac.appcategoryid JOIN
     BR_APPUSER au
     ON a.appuserid = au.appuserid
GROUP BY a.appname, ac.categoryname;
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a ```ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00904: "A"."AppUserId": invalid identifier```, I added the double quotation marks to all the tables you listed but it still persists

Comment: You've included ```ON a.appuserid = au.appuserid``` but ```userid``` doesn't exist in the BR_APP table

Comment: I've replaced ```appuserid``` with ```appid``` and it works as intended, thank you once again, I'll be sure to pass on the struggles with sql to my professor

Comment: @UnboundPhantom in your example you referred to `au."AppUserId"`, which is not the same as `au.appuserid`.